# Modbus registers can be only read and cannot be written

Tags: controller, minimalmodbus

I am trying communicate via Modbus protocol to a uC2 SE controller for a air-water chiller. A serial RS485 to USB port COM is connected with the controller and I was able to read registers, but it is not possible to change their values by using write_register function. I have also tried with tester. exe and Modscan64 softwares and the result was the same, they only can read but not write. I have introduced here the piece of code is being run and debug responses can be checked. Thank you for your help in advance!

## Change temperature setpoint

COOLING_SETPOINT_REG = 41

try:
print(instrument.read_register(COOLING_SETPOINT_REG,1))
except IOError:
print('Failed to read from instrument')

NEW_TEMPERATURE = 20.1

return_flag = instrument.write_register(COOLING_SETPOINT_REG, NEW_TEMPERATURE,1,functioncode = 6, signed = True) # Registernumber, value, number of decimals for storage
output_flag = 'SUCCESS' if return_flag else 'FAILURE'
print('writing single register status  ' + output_flag + '\n' )

### try:
print(instrument.read_register(COOLING_SETPOINT_REG,1))
except IOError:
print('Failed to read from instrument')

Respuesta debug:

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): '\x01\x03\x00)\x00\x01UÂ' (01 03 00 29 00 01 55 C2)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 334030.00 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x01\x03\x02\x00È¹Ò' (01 03 02 00 C8 B9 D2) (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 1000.0 ms.

20.0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 8 bytes back): '\x01\x06\x00)\x00É\x98T' (01 06 00 29 00 C9 98 54)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 47.00 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x01\x06\x00)\x00É\x98T' (01 06 00 29 00 C9 98 54) (8 bytes), roundtrip time: 47.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 1000.0 ms.

writing single register status  FAILURE

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 7 bytes back): '\x01\x03\x00)\x00\x01UÂ' (01 03 00 29 00 01 55 C2)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Opening port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 46.00 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Closing port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x01\x03\x02\x00È¹Ò' (01 03 02 00 C8 B9 D2) (7 bytes), roundtrip time: 47.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 1000.0 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to write parameters in Carel controllers uC Compact and uC2 SE Process by means of a Modbus protocol, because they are not configured for it. For this purpose, only a Carel protocol can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Writing is successful.

write_register from minimalmodbus has "None" return value.

So checking the return_flag results in failure.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer, but it seems that the slave can read the writing message and respond that it is out of range. It seems that Carel controller would require some kind of permission, dont know!

Comment: Response from instrument: '\x01\x06\x00)\x00É\x98T' (01 06 00 29 00 C9 98 54) (8 bytes). 
This means that write was successful. 
Register with address 0029 now has the value 00C9.
Maybe the value changes back, before the next read is performed.

Comment: Thank you again, I did not notice the information regarding the payload, sorry I am quite new on this stuff. But, it is curious, since I have tried also different softwares like tester from Schneider or Modscan, and they all read properly but cannot write, and none error message is shown. Should I run programs with administrator rights, and not as a user?? Certainly, changing parameters manually requires a password set in the controller. I am also waiting some help from Carel, and meanwhile I'll keep trying.